# Jenkins windows batch file user input: Press any key to start issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, keyboard-input

I am trying to run a windows batch file by jenkins on slave windows machine.
The batch file requires “Press any key to continue” input which is not possible atleast for me during job build. Any ideas how can i pass keyboard input to batch file during build run. Thanks

Comment: Most likely coming from a `PAUSE` command.  I would just remove it from the batch file.